# How to retreive equivalent records for a specific person's record in a specific month using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an assignment which is to view names of the top 3 high achievers in my department. A high achiever is a regular employee who stayed the longest hours in the company for a certain month and all tasks assigned to him/her with a deadline of this month are fixed. My query :

```
 SELECT  distinct top 3   Regular_Employees.username , 
 DATEDIFF(HOUR,start_time,end_time)
 FROM Regular_Employees INNER JOIN Staff_Members on     
 Regular_Employees.username=Staff_Members.username INNER JOIN Tasks ON 
 Staff_Members.username=Tasks.regular_employee INNER join Attendance_Records 
 on Regular_Employees.username = Attendance_Records.staff
 WHERE MONTH(deadline) = MONTH('11/11/2017') AND YEAR(deadline) = 
 YEAR('11/11/2017') AND department=Staff_Members.department
 ORDER BY DATEDIFF(HOUR,start_time,end_time) DESC
```

I wanted to retrieve top 3 records in November and the result was

```
     daniel.magdi   2
     farid.elsoury  2
     joy.ahmed  2
```

where the employees are the right employees while the records '2' is the record for one day not the whole month. How can i compute the record for each employee per whole month and view the results ?

I want to insert date as ' 11/11/2017' and the result would be
 Result

```
  Employee      HOURS 
  daniel.magdi    180 
  farid.elsoury   179 
  joy.ahmed       175
```

where those are the highest records in November

Comment: put sample data and expected result

Comment: I want to insert date as ' 11/11/2017' and the result would be 

Result     

Employee                HOURS

daniel.magdi              180 
farid.elsoury                179
joy.ahmed                    175 


where those are the highest records in November

Comment: In what sense is this query 'implemented'?

Comment: With SELECT TOP are you sure this is Mysql and not Sqlserver ?